# Will the DLC for Mortal Kombat 2011 affect achievement completion?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, mortal-kombat-9

There are several achievements in the newest Mortal Kombat game that require you to do something with every single character. These include:

- **Arcade Champion** - complete arcade mode with all fighters
- **e-X-cellent!** - land every playable fighter's X-Ray attack
- **Finish What You Start!** - perform a Fatality with all playable fighters
- **My Kung Fu Is Stronger** - gain mastery of all fighters
- **The Grappler** - perform every fighter's forwards and backwards throws
- **Ultimate Humiliation** - perform every fighter's hidden finishing move

Will downloading the extra characters offered through the DLC affect the requirements for these achievements if you have not received them yet?

For example, if I have completed Arcade Mode with everyone except Sub-Zero, without the DLC, once I finish with arcade mode with Sub-Zero, I would normally receive "Arcade Champion."

Let's say I download Skarlet before I finish Arcade Mode with Sub-Zero. Will I only be awarded "Arcade Champion" once I have finished arcade mode with *both* characters?

Will this same scenario apply to the other achievements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that OliverBM's assumption seems to be correct and **DLC characters are not counted towards these milestone achievements**. I would've preferred more authoritative sources, but posted user experiences was the best I could do for most of them.

According to [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mortal-kombat/Arcade_Champion), the **Arcade Champion achievement does not include the DLC characters**, but does include the unlockable characters:

> Tag Ladder does count: You get this achievement when you beat the standard or tag ladder **with each of the non-DLC 27 characters (28 on the PS3 version)**. You can use as many continues as you wish, and you can do this on any difficulty level.

According to [this answer](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/961031-mortal-kombat/answers?qid=291445), **Finish What You Start! does not include DLC characters**, but note from reading elsewhere that it does include the unlockable characters:

> And no, **DLC characters dont count towards the trophy**.

According to this thread on [xbox360achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/mortal-kombat/achievement/51562-My-Kung-Fu-Is-Stronger.html#111), **My Kung Fu Is Stronger does not include the DLC characters**, but does include the unlockable characters:

> -#112, just to be absolutely clear, **even if I have the DLC characters, it only counts towards the originals**?
>
> -that is correct

According to [this post](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/2643311-post386.html), e-X-cellent!, The Grappler, and Ultimate Humiliation do not include the DLC characters**, but from reading elsewhere do include the unlockable characters:

> It seems that **DLC characters are not needed for trophies**, I got milestone trophies (Finish What You Start !, Ultimate Humiliation, The Grappler, e-X-cellent...) without playing with Rain, Kenshi, Skarlet and Freddy.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is highly unlikely that you would be forced to accomplish this achievement with the characters from any DLC pack.

My reason for this is simple, Achievements are completed when certain parameters are met and these are programmed in when the game is made. Therefore the achievement can never ask you to do things with characters/data it doesn't have.

I hope this helps.

PS there is the possibility that new achievements will be added with a similar nature to the ones you've linked that are concerned with the new characters.

Comment: It depends on how the game is storing the data, and how the game is checking the data for achievements. If each character has a "completed arcade mode" flag, the achievement could theoretically query the list of each character and return the fraction of flagged characters to non-flagged characters, and anything less than 1 wouldn't earn the achievement. In this specific circumstance, I think you are probably right, but it is unknowable without actually experimenting.

Comment: Good point it really does depend on how the game stores data I just described it how I would store the data but then again i'm not a game developer I guess the game stores achievement data like other games?

Comment: @Oliver The main reason I ask is because I know of at least one instance (Magic the Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers) where the 100% completion achievement in the base game *did* change with the addition of DLC. I've so far refrained from purchasing the DLC until I complete the base game because of this. Given the large amount of time you have to put in for the some of these achievements (*literally* 24 hours per character for the **My Kung Fu is Stronger** achievement), I want this knowledge ahead of time.

Comment: Ok well in that case and I would then refrain from buying the DLC just to be safe (have you contacted the developer about this query?)